# What's the weird file name .rb. with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Today I run rspec in rails, and there're weird thing happened, I find rspec always show the error bellow, even thought I'm very sure I have corresponded the file name, struggle about three hours, finally I find rspec show the error message `An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/concerns/mixpanel_tracking_spec.rb.`, please looks carefully, the end of filename more one `.`, that's weird so that I type `ls` look my file name right now, It show correct file name `mixpanel_tracking_spec.rb` with no `.`, finally I recreate a new rspec file and the rspec work, and I also try use touch to create `touch mixpanel_tracking_spec.rb.` and type `ls` then it show `mixpanel_tracking_spec.rb.` with point `.`

So there is a question, what happend for there? How can create a file name with end point `mixpanel_tracking_spec.rb.` but use `ls` show `mixpanel_tracking_spec.rb`, by my experiment, it looks like impossible, and what's the meaning of the file name `.rb.`, does it has any association with ruby?

## rspec error

`NameError:
  uninitialized constant MixpanelTracking`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably an error inside your `mixpanel_tracking_spec.rb`

Rspec adds a dot in the end of sentence. It's not looking for a file named `mixpanel_tracking_spec.rb.`

Check this snipplet:

```
reporter.notify_non_example_exception(ex, "An error occurred while loading #{relative_file}.")
```

Rspec relevant source: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L1925

Comment: you're right, it looks like just a error message, but that's weird why's my rspec alaways fail by the truth, anyway, finally my rspec can work, thanks for your explain.